# Simple Hangman implementation in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, hangman

I'm starting out with Rust and decided to implement a game of Hangman. Can you please provide general feedback on the code?

I've already identified some lines (see comments `[A]`, `[B]`, `[C]`) where I cannot find a better way; feedback regarding these would be much appreciated as well.

```rust
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;
use std::io::stdin;

const MAX_ALLOWED_ERRORS: i32 = 7;

fn main() {
    println!("\nWelcome to Hangman!\n");

    let to_guess = generate_word();
    let mut display = str::repeat("_ ", to_guess.len());
    println!("{}", display);

    let mut nb_errors = 0;

    loop {
        let mut user_input = String::new();
        stdin().read_line(&mut user_input).expect("Could not read user input");

        match extract_and_capitalize_first_letter(&user_input) {
            Ok(user_guess) => {
                println!("You guessed: {}", user_guess);

                let (is_error, is_full, new_display) = compute_displayed_word(
                    &to_guess, &Some(display), &user_guess,
                );
                // [A] Is there a way to avoid this? Ideally, I would like
                //     to use the same variable for storing the result as
                //     the one passed as the argument
                display = new_display;

                if is_error {
                    nb_errors += 1;
                }

                if is_full {
                    println!("You win!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Could not process your input");
                nb_errors += 1;
            }
        }

        println!("Error counter: {}", nb_errors);  // maybe later print a real hangman
        if nb_errors > MAX_ALLOWED_ERRORS {
            println!("You lose! The word was: {}", to_guess);
            break;
        }

        println!("{}", display);
    }
}

// return the string to display along with 2 booleans:
// 1. indicating if an error should be counted
// 2. indicating if the word is fully guessed
fn compute_displayed_word(
    word: &String,
    current_display: &Option<String>,
    guess: &char,
) -> (bool, bool, String) {
    let mut is_error = true;
    let mut is_full = true;
    // [B] Should I work with a Vec<char>, or is a mutable String ok?
    let mut new_display = "".to_string();

    for (i, letter) in word.chars().enumerate() {
        if letter.to_ascii_uppercase().eq(guess) {
            is_error = false;
            new_display.push(*guess);
        } else {
            let letter_to_display = match current_display {
                // [C] I couldn't find a way to not do the .chars().collect()
                //     at each iteration, apparently this is due to the
                //     absence of Copy implementation in Vec<char>
                Some(d) => d.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>()[i * 2],
                _ => '_'
            };
            if letter_to_display.eq(&'_') {
                is_full = false;
            }
            new_display.push(letter_to_display);
        }
        new_display.push(' ');
    }
    (is_error, is_full, new_display)
}

fn generate_word() -> String {
    let all_words = vec!["test", "cat", "dog", "controller", "operation", "jazz"];
    let chosen_word = all_words.choose(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    match chosen_word {
        Some(&s) => {
            return s.to_string();
        }
        None => panic!("Could not choose a word!")
    }
}

fn extract_and_capitalize_first_letter(s: &String) -> Result<char, String> {
    return match s.chars().nth(0) {
        Some(c) => {
            if !c.is_ascii_alphabetic() {
                return Err("Only alphabetic characters allowed".to_string());
            }

            Ok(c.to_ascii_uppercase())
        }
        None => Err("Empty string".to_string()),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest improvement that you can make is to not store your state in a String. You'll find things much easier if you store your state in appropriate data structures.

It'll also be easier to understand you code if you organize the current state of the game into a struct rather then across a collection of local variables.

Here I'd do something like:

```
struct Game {
   word_to_guess: String,
   guesses: HashSet<char>
}

impl Game {
    fn display(&self) -> String {
       // return the f _ _ _ _ t string you want
    }

    fn errors(&self) -> usize {
       // count the number of guesses that aren't contained in the word
    }

    fn is_full(&self) -> bool {
       // return true if all the chars in the word are in guesses
    }
}
```

You could also use a `Vec<bool>` to represent which letters are uncovered.

> ```
>             // [A] Is there a way to avoid this? Ideally, I would like
>             //     to use the same variable for storing the result as
>             //     the one passed as the argument
> ```

If you want the function to essentially modify the `display` variable, you should pass it via a `&mut` parameter.

> ```
> // [B] Should I work with a Vec<char>, or is a mutable String ok?
> ```

As explained above, you should do neither, but choose an appropriate data structure to represent the logical state of the game.

> // [C] I couldn't find a way to not do the .chars().collect()
> //     at each iteration, apparently this is due to the
> //     absence of Copy implementation in Vec

Rust doesn't provide indexing into strings. That's a deliberate choice because indexing into unicode strings is almost always the wrong thing to do. This is rather another reason to store the state in appropriate data structures rather then trying to read your state into and out of a String.

Comment: This is a great answer! I'll give all these suggestions a try. On a purely theoretical view, will the implementation of those `Game` functions not be computationally worse? I only needed to read the String once per guess. Either way, the improvement in readability is so big with your idea!

Comment: @BusyAnt, yes, there is some performance lost in my approach. But in the case that the loss is big enough to care about, you can add cached/precomputed values to the Game struct and get that back. However, its best to avoid adding such optimizations until they are needed.